# wordpress website behind AWS Application load balancer

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I created Application Load Balancer in AWS and installed word press website on ec2-instance. I can access website fine if I access using the public ip address of ec2-instance. However, I cannot access the pages whenever I try to access using DNS Name of Application Load Balancer. The error code returned by chrome is `301`.

Security Group of instance allows all traffic from load balancer at port 80.

There is nothing in the access logs or error logs. I have no experience dealing with wordpress. Please let me know if I can provide any further information to find issue.

Edit:
If I place the same instance behind `Classic Load Balancer`, instead of `Application Load Balancer`, then it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`301` is a redirect, not an error code. You probably need to configure your custom domain to point to the load balancer, then configure Wordpress to be aware of the domain name so it won't try to redirect.

Comment: Hi Mark, I know it sounds like stupid question but how do I make word press aware of domain name? As of now, there is no custom domain which is pointing to load balancer. I am accessing directly via load balancer dns name exposed by aws.

Comment: @Zohaib I'm not a wordpress expert, but I believe you need to configure the `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` settings in your wordpress configuration. It looks like you can also set this in the Wordpress dashboard under Settings->General. If you search for "wordpress domain name configuration" you will get tons of results showing you how to do this.

Comment: I have a similar setup, but i am trying to use ALB and Cloudfront. When i configured my site url and home to domain name associated with ALB and then try to access
https://cloudfront-alternate-domain/wp-admin, it is redirecting (302) to the ALB. 
I am able to just browse through the cloudfront URL, but when i click few buttons on the website, it agains redirects from the CF URL to AWS LB URL.

Comment: What is the recommended approach here?

Comment: @GauravParashar go into Wordpress -> Settings -> General, and configure the Wordpress Address setting to be the CloudFront domain name. It sounds like it is currently configured to be the ALB domain name, which is why it is redirecting. You might also need to set the domain in Apache or Nginx also depending on what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you installed WordPress directly by accessing the ec2 instance?

I can remember a similar problem with WordPress making redirections (301) when it has been installed via a wrong domain. If it is an option, reinstalling WordPress directly through the Load Balancer should fix this problem.